# How do you read a text file but in a certain path java

Tags: java

I have a read method which gets the key and a value from a text file so for example if I have:

```
Name: <name>
```

it would get the value

The only thing in mind was using properties but I don't really know how to apply them for paths example:

```
Students:
Name: <Name>
```

I want to get something like this `read("students.name");`
and the output would be the name

What I've done till now

```
public String read () {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()));
        for(String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            return value;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

@TimBiegeleisen this is what I've tried right now maybe you could help me?

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I want to do a method which returns me a value from a text file for example,
Students:
Name: <value>

Comment: I noticed your key `students` does it means that your property file will store information about many students? Or is it only for one student?

Comment: Many students Example `Students: Name: <name1> Name: <name2>`

Comment: In that case, a property file is not the best choice. You can better use an XML file or a simple text file with the JSON format

Comment: Okay thanks will check them out :)

Answer (score 0):

To use a properties file, your data must be in the proper format.  For your example above, you would need your properties file to look like:

```
students.name=Ed
```

If you want to use a format like you have listed, i.e.

```
Students:
Name: Ed
```

then you would need to write your own parsing mechanism to extract the data.

I just saw the comment that you will have multiple names under "Students".  That makes a properties file not useful and your code itself would need to return an ArrayList or something if you plan to read all the names at once.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm planning to have more than one name

Answer (score 0):

If you go on with `Properties`, you need to slightly change the [format of your file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties):

```
students.name1 = <name1>
students.name2 = <name2>
```

I personally would assigne the `Properties`object to a `static`variable in order to ne load the same file each time you call `read` so your method would become:

```
public String read (String key) {
    if(properties == null){
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()));
            properties = prop;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
     if(properties != null){
        return properties.get(key);
     }
     return null;
}
```

That way if you call `read("students.name1")`, you get the name of the first student.

Note that if you want to get a collection of students with the key "students" for example, you can consider [JSON](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html), [XML](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html) or [YAML](http://yaml.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will try this out after I try out XML